# Dynamic image path in Ionic 2 doesn't work on device

Tags: ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2.2 and normally I reference the pictures like this:

```
<img  src="assets/images/img.svg" />
```

Which works fine in both browser and device.

But our app uses themes, and I need to change the image folder based on which theme the user selects.

In my html:

```
<img src="{{getImagePath('image1.svg')}}">
```

In typescript file:

```
  getImagePath(img){
    if(this.theme == 'special'){
      return 'assets/images/special/' + img;
    } else {
      return 'assets/images/' + img;
    }
  }
```

This works in browser but, not in device.

What is the correct way to do this?
I also tried `[src]="getImagePath('image1.svg')"` which had the same result. And tried to play with the path like `../assets` and couple other variation but couldn't find the right way.

Comment: it is `[src]="getImagePath('image1.svg')` is that a typo?

Comment: yes it was typo sorry, I tried [src]="getImagePath('image1.svg') and it works in the browser but not on real android device.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that reinstalling the platform and plugins solved my issue.
The code in the question is correct and now working on android device.